# How to parse parameters from JSON file in python as a string?

Tags: python, json, unicode

I am a newbie in python.
I am trying to read some parameters from a JSON file and pass it as parameters in a command through the python os.system module.

Following is my code:

```
import json
jdata = open('Az.json').read()
params = json.loads(jdata)
os.system('export rg=%s' %params['global'])
```

the Az.Json file is basically a dictionary, and I am trying to set the environment variable 'rg' by reading the value associated with the 'global' key in the dictionary.

But, my code is not working because it is reading it in Unicode format. I am not able to convert that Unicode data to string. Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: str(params['global'])?

Comment: And you can use the json.load to load the json data from the file directly instead of using open & read

Comment: What do you mean with "my code is not working"? Do you have an error, and can you post that?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. It's just that, the 'rg' variable is not getting assigned. It's like it's not reading the 'global' key

Comment: try to print `params['global']` and `'export rg=%s' %params['global']` before calling `os.system('export rg=%s' %params['global'])`. Your code should work

Answer (score 2):

You can use the os module to set the environment variable using os.environ

**EX:**

```
import os
import json
jdata = json.load(open('Az.json'))
os.environ["rg"] = str(jdata['global'])
```